# Emulating \@ifnextchar in expl3

Tags: latex3, expl3

I would like to write an expl3 version of the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\ie{i.e\@ifnextchar.{}{.\@{} }}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ie Hello\newline
\ie. Hello\newline
\end{document}
```

I'm aware of the `\peek_after:Nw` command, but I don't understand how to implement it.  In fact, all the `\peek_...` commands seem to require you to explicitly feed it a *token*.  I seem to have to write a command which takes arguments.

I could try something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\eg}{ m }
    {
        e.g
        \str_if_eq_x:nnF { . } { #1 }{.\@{} }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\eg Hello\newline
\eg. Hello\newline
{\eg} Hello
\end{document}
```

But there are a couple of sticking points.

First, because `\eg` is defined to take an argument, it gobbles up the following `H` in the first instance.  `\ie` doesn't have this problem.  (I could get around this by writing something like `\str_if_eq_x:nnF { . } { #1 }{.\@{} #1}`, but in my *real* document for which all of this is a greatly reduced MWE, I run into more issues when `#1` contains something that's not a character.)

Second, `{\eg}` creates an error because it's expecting an argument but encounters what it believes are *unbalanced* parentheses.  Again, `{\ie}` very nicely does not have this issue.

So this approach is really not what I'm looking for.

Here's my attempt at using `\peek_after:Nw`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \ae_eg: 
    {
        \peek_after:Nw \ae_test_period:
    }

\cs_new:Nn \ae_test_period: 
    {
        \str_if_eq_x:nnF  { \l_peek_token }  { . }  { FALSE }
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\eg}{}
    {
        e.g \ae_eg:
    }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\eg. Hello\newline
\eg  Hello\newline
\end{document}
```

But `\l_peek_token` is never seen to be the same as `.`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking in the right place with `\peek_after:wN`, but that is the most low-level function (a wrapper around `\futurelet`). What you want is `\peek_meaning:NF`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \ie } { }
  {
    i.e
    \peek_meaning:NF . % Just a 'false' branch needed
       { . \@ ~ }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\ie Hello\newline
\ie. Hello\newline
\end{document}
```

`\@ifnextchar` does its comparison using `\ifx`, which is `meaning` in `expl3` term. `\@ifnextchar` also skips spaces, which is not relevant here but might mean you want `\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:N(TF)`, depending on the full context.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I'm using the wrong *equality* test:  I should have written:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF {NnTF}
\cs_new:Nn \ae_test_period: 
    {
        \token_if_eq_meaning:NnTF  \l_peek_token   { . } {  }  { .\@{~} }
    }
```