# Avoid passing an empty [optional argument] an environment (with verbatim content) using xparse?

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse, optional-arguments

this query is related to [How to pass an optional argument to an environment with verbatim content?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9035) (whose solution did not work in my case) and with [Emulating @ifnextchar in expl3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116802) (which is the one I'm trying to adapt).

I have defined an environment (`listcontents`) using `xparse` which encapsulates `\filecontentsdef` (which is `verbatim` plus `\macro`) using the argument `!O{}` and `[key = val]` which works well if **ALWAYS** pass the optional argument.

My idea is to be able to write the environment without having to use an empty optional argument `[]`, this is where I am lost, I have read the documentation of `\peek_meaning:NF` but I do not understand it at all (the `\catcodes` is confusing for me).

It works correctly if use:

```
\begin{listcontents}[]
\begin{listcontents}[key=val]
\begin{listcontents}[
                    key=val
                    ]
```

and I would like to do it in the following way:

```
\begin{listcontents}
\begin{listcontents}
[not key = value, only a bracket whit text]
```

that is, if you do not find `[key = val]` right after `}`, insert a line ending `\^^M` and `[not key = value, just a square bracket with text]` would be recorded by the environment. 
The package `xsim` (which is written only using`expl3`) works similar to `filecontents`, has a code to solve this problem, but, it is very complicated to adapt for me.

This is my sample file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,filecontentsdef,xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { listcontents }
  {
    save-env   .tl_set:N         = \l_env_save_tl,
    save-env   .initial:n        = content,
    show-env   .bool_set:N       = \l_env_show_tl,
    show-env   .initial:n        = true,
    name-tmp   .tl_set:N         = \l_tmp_name_tl,
    name-tmp   .initial:n        = \jobname.tsc,
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ listcontents }{ !O{} }
  {
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF { #1 } { \keys_set:nn { listcontents } { #1 } }
  %\peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NF [ { \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M \char_set_catcode_end_line:N \^^M  \\ }
  %\peek_meaning:NF \c_space_tl { \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M \char_set_catcode_end_line:N \^^M  \^^M  }
  % Acording a doc of v1.4 this its a correct line 
   \csname filecontentsdef*\endcsname{ \l_tmp_name_tl }{ \l_tmpa_tl }
   }
  {
  \endfilecontentsdef
  \group_end:
  \group_begin:
  \IfNoValueF { #1 } { \keys_set:nn { listcontents } { #1 } }
  \IfBooleanT{ \l_env_show_tl } { \filecontentsexec\l_tmpa_tl }
  \group_end:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\section{[not key = value, just a square bracket with text]}
\begin{listcontents} 
[not key = value, just a square bracket with text]
This is correct for key=val, but space between letters in [...] disappeared
% some comented lines
\begin{verbatim*}
\begin{listcontents}
[not key = value, just a square bracket with text]
\end{verbatim*}
and \verb+[not key = value, just a square bracket with text]+ its not save 
in \verb+\jobname.tsc+ and \verb+\l_tmpa_tl+.
\end{listcontents}

The \textbf{file generate} is:
\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname.tsc}

\section{Omit a [optional argument] after begin\{listcontents\} }
\begin{listcontents}
This is what I want to happen when omit []
% some comented lines
\begin{verbatim*}
\begin{listcontents}
This is what I want to happen when omit []
% some comented lines
\end{verbatim*}
if ommit \verb*+[ ]+ the first lines and and space between 
letters disappeared, the contents of environments not save 
in \verb+\jobname.tsc+ and \verb+\l_tmpa_tl+.
\end{listcontents}

The \textbf{file generate} is:
\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname.tsc}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: output looks]
Can this be done using `xparse/expl3`?

regards

Comment: I think that you just want `\NewDocumentEnvironment{ listcontents }{o}` and then continue with `\IfNoValueF { #1 }{...}` in the environment definition. Now both `\begin{listcontents}...\end{listcontents}` and `\begin{listcontents}[show-env=true]...\end{listcontents}` are valid.

Comment: @Andrew: Thanks, it was the first thing I tried, but using `{o}` is not enough for what I want.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108897/verbatim-like-environment-with-optional-arguments-poorly-behaved and this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109030/optional-arguments-in-verbatim-environments

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do. Does `{o!}` give what you want? Certainly using `{O{}}` followed by `\IfNoValueF{#1}{...}` makes no sense because `O` sets `#1` to `{}` if no argument is given so `\IfNoValueF{#1}{...}` will *always* execute `{...}`.

Comment: @Andrew Have you tried ?, I only get
`! LaTeX3 Error: The key 'listcontents / just a square bracket with text'`

Comment: Sorry, it should be `{!o}`. This works for me and, as far as I understand it, does something that might be what you want - but, as I said, I'm not sure what you want. In any case, your MWE compiles when using `{!o}`.

Comment: @Andrew : I use `TeXLive 2019` (fedora / win10) and the MWE does not work as expected...any ideas?

Comment: `\filecontentsdef` juggles with the category code of the endline character; when no optional argument is used, it's too late because the endline character after `\begin{listcontents}` has already been scanned and converted to a space, which has the effect of not including the following line in the contents; the text is typeset that way because of how `\filecontentsdef` sets things up.

Comment: @egreg Ok, I understand, is there no way to "skip" this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to delay the search for the optional argument, because otherwise the endline character after `\begin{listcontent}` is subject to tokenization and converted to a space before `\filecontentsdef` can act

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb,filecontentsdef,xparse}
\pagestyle{empty}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { listcontents }
  {
    save-env   .tl_set:N         = \l_env_save_tl,
    save-env   .initial:n        = content,
    show-env   .bool_set:N       = \l_env_show_bool,
    show-env   .initial:n        = true,
    name-tmp   .tl_set:N         = \l_tmp_name_tl,
    name-tmp   .initial:n        = \c_sys_jobname_str.tsc,
    save-macro .bool_set:N       = \l_save_macro_bool,
    save-macro .initial:n        = true,
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment{ listcontents }{}
  {
   \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
   \pedro_start_listcontents:w
  }
  {
   \endfilecontentsdef
   \group_end:
   \IfBooleanT{ \l_env_show_bool } { \filecontentsexec\l_tmpa_tl }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pedro_listcontents_set:w [#1]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { listcontents } { #1 }
 }

\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pedro_start_listcontents:w #1 ^^M
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \pedro_listcontents_set:w #1 }
  \group_begin:
  \use:c { filecontentsdef* } { \l_tmp_name_tl } { \l_tmpa_tl } ^^M
  }
\group_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{No optional argument}
\begin{listcontents}
[text in brackets]
Some text
% a comment
\begin{verbatim*}
\foo
\end{verbatim*}
Some text
\end{listcontents}

The \textbf{generated file} is:
\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname.tsc}

\section{Optional argument}
\begin{listcontents}[name-tmp=\jobname-2.tsc]
Some text
% a comment
\begin{verbatim*}
\foo
\end{verbatim*}
Some text
\end{listcontents}

The \textbf{generated file} is:
\VerbatimInput[frame=single]{\jobname-2.tsc}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly, I almost achieved something by copying the `xsim` code, but yours is much more readable and has allowed me to finish with my project. You can look at this question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/487828/7832) related to this topic?...Saludos y Gracias Totales :)

Comment: egreg: If you have some time, you could place an alternative response that
accept `{listcontents}[key val whit vertical space]`. Greetings.