# What is the maximum limit of elements in a list (expl3/xparse)?

Tags: tex-core, expl3, latex3

I have a query with the maximum number of items that can be saved in an `expl3` list. Thanks to the response that @egreg gave me in [Avoid passing an empty [optional argument] an environment (with verbatim content) using xparse?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487746/7832) I was able to finish the implementation of an environment capable of saving valid `LaTeX` code (including `verbatim`) in `expl3`lists ... something like a "ConTextbuffers".

Let me explain a bit, I have many question/answer files in which I have abused the use of `filecontents` to record temporary files and  included them in environment based on  `environ` (which did not support `verbatim`) and then use them in different parts of the documents.

With the new version of `filecontentsdef` it is not necessary to write the external files (included `verbatim`) to have them in a `\macro`, thus the things and gathering ideas I have managed to create a `scontents` environment which encapsulates `\filecontentsdefmacro`, what run and save in a `seq` list, which I can access with `\getstored[index]{seq name}`, the environment and command `Scontents` works perfectly.

My question is this, the environment expands the content of `\macro` and stores in sequence, the command stores direct in sequence (same or other), at some point the `seq` list will have a limit. **What is the limit on the number of items I can save?**

I have tested some files, but, I convert all my old files using a `script` to pass them to the new `scontents` environment.

I leave here the example code using `l3seq`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}[2019/04/20]
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor,fvextra} % only for example
\pagestyle{empty}           % only for example
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % only for example
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl }

\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    save-env  .tl_set:N   = \l_scontents_name_seq_tl,
    save-env  .initial:n  = contents,
    show-env  .bool_set:N = \l_scontents_show_env_bool,
    show-env  .initial:n  = false,
    save-cmd  .tl_set:N   = \l_scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl,
    save-cmd  .initial:n  = contents,
    show-cmd  .bool_set:N = \l_scontents_show_cmd_bool,
    show-cmd  .initial:n  = false
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_append_contents:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      {
        \seq_new:c { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } {#2}
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } {#1}
  }

\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{ \countseqsc }{ m }
  {
    \seq_count:c { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
  }

\keys_define:nn { scontents / Scontents }
  {
    show-cmd  .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { scontents } { show-cmd = #1 } },
    save-cmd  .code:n = { \keys_set:nn { scontents } { save-cmd = #1 } }
  }

\ProvideDocumentCommand{ \Scontents }{ O{} +m }
  {
    \group_begin:
    \IfNoValueF {#1} { \keys_set:nn { scontents / Scontents } {#1} }
    \_scontents_append_contents:nn { \l_scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl } { #2 } % add to seq
    \bool_if:NT \l_scontents_show_cmd_bool
      {
        \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { -1 }{ \l_scontents_name_seq_cmd_tl }
      }
    \group_end:
  }

\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{ \getstored }{ O{1} m }
  {
    \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn {#1} {#2}
  }

\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{ scontents }{}
  {
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \scontents_start_environment:w
  }
  {
    \scontents_stop_environment:
    \scontents_atend_environment:
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_environment_keys:w [#1]
  {
    \keys_set:nn { scontents } {#1}
  }

% Star environment
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_start_environment:w #1 ^^M
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} { \scontents_environment_keys:w #1 }
    \group_begin: % open group for env
    \use:c { filecontentsdefmacro } { \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } ^^M 
  }
\group_end:

% Stop environment
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_stop_environment:
  {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro 
    \group_end:  % close group for env
  }

% A variant to replace \^^M for \^^J (need by Verb{..} from fvextra)
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_replace_all:Nnn { Nxx } 

% Expand \l_tmpa_tl and pass to seq
\cs_gset_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  { 
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { \^^M } { \^^J } \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \cs_log:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
    \exp_args:NNx \_scontents_append_contents:nn \l_scontents_name_seq_tl 
      {
       \exp_not:N \scantokens \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl} } %
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_atend_environment:
  {
    \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
    \bool_if:NT \l_scontents_show_env_bool
      {
        \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { -1 }{ \l_scontents_name_seq_tl }
      }
    \cs_undefine:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\section{Test \Verb{\begin{scontents}[key=val]}}
Test \verb+\begin{scontents}+ no \verb+[key=val]+\par

\begin{scontents}
Using \Verb{scontents} env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in seq \verb+contents+ with index 1.\par
\begin{verbatim}
      (A) verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}

Test \verb+\begin{scontents}[show-env=true]+\par

\begin{scontents}[show-env=true]
Using \verb+scontents+ env with \Verb{[show-env=true]}, save in seq \verb+contents+ with index 2.
We have coded this in \LaTeX: $E=mc^2$.\par
\begin{Verbatim*}
      (B) verbatim environment
\end{Verbatim*}
\end{scontents}

Test \verb+\begin{scontents}[show-env=false]+\par

\begin{scontents}[show-env=false]
Using \verb+scontents+ env with \verb+[show-env=false]+, save in seq \verb+contents+ with index 3. 
We have coded this in \LaTeX: $E=mc^2$.\par
\begin{verbatim}
      (C) verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}

Test \verb+\begin{scontents}[show-env=true]+\par

\begin{scontents}[show-env=true]
Using \verb+scontents+ env with \verb+[show-env=true]+, save in seq \verb+contents+ with index 4.
We have coded this in \LaTeX: $E=mc^2$.\par
\begin{verbatim*}
      (D) verbatim environment
\end{verbatim*}
\end{scontents}

Test \verb+\Scontents{...}+\par
\Scontents{Using \texttt{Scontents} command (no verbatim), save in seq \texttt{contents} with index 5}

\section{Test \Verb{\getstored[index]{contents}}}
The total contents stored  in \verb+contents+ seq are \countseqsc{contents}.\par

\getstored[5]{contents}\par
\getstored{contents}

\section{A simple aplication using \Verb{pgffor} loop}
\newcounter{exeNr}
\newenvironment{exercise}
  {\refstepcounter{exeNr}\par\noindent This is exercise~\theexeNr}
  {\par}
\subsection{Exercises}
\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\begin{scontents}[save-env = myansewer]
This is the answer to exercise 1, the shebang line for a Perl script

\begin{verbatim}
#!/usr/bin/env perl
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}

\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\begin{scontents}[save-env = myansewer]
This is the answer to exercise 2
\end{scontents}

\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\Scontents[save-cmd = myansewer]{This is the answer to exercise 3}

\subsection{Answers}
\newcounter{ansNr}
\newenvironment{answer}
  {\refstepcounter{ansNr}\par\noindent Answer~\theansNr:}
  {\par}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\countseqsc{myansewer}} {
\begin{answer}
\getstored[\i]{myansewer}
\end{answer}
}

\end{document}
```

An image of what the output is like:
[image: output example]

Annexed query, `expl3` provides two modules `l3seq` and `l3prop` to store data, is there any difference in this specific case?

Regards

Comment: I didn't read you whole code so I don't know precisely what it does. But an `expl3` seq variable is a macro deep down, so if you are inserting contents in a seq variable you are basically doing a very large `\def`. In this case, your limit will probably be the `words of memory` memory, where in the (my) log there is `XX words of memory out of 5000000`. But the amount of _items_ in a seq variable is probably unlimited. The amount you can actually store will depend on the “size” of each element.

Comment: The coding is quite bizarre. Please, avoid `@` as much as possible and also `\scantokens`: you should be aware of `\tl_rescan:nn`. The maximum limit of items in a list/sequence is “what can be stored in memory”.

Comment: I have removed the `@` and the unused code, use `\ tl_rescan: nn` instead of `\scantokens` not work for me (help at this point appreciated). @egreg or @Phelype Oleinik, if the answer to my question is "what can be stored in memory", please leave it as an answer to not leave the question open. Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Sorry, I didn't receive your ping in the comment above (only one person can be pinged, so probably egreg was). I added a rough calculation of the amount of stuff you can add to the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, to start your code seems to add stuff to an `expl3` `seq` variable (before the edit, now they are `prop` variables, but the difference is not much in terms of memory consumption). A `seq` variable is nothing but a macro which contains the items you added to that sequence. For example, after you do `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {a,b,c}`, the `seq` variable will be a macro with:

```latex
\s__seq
\__seq_item:n {a}
\__seq_item:n {b}
\__seq_item:n {c}
```

An arbitrarily large sequence variable will be a macro with arbitrarily many `\__seq_item:n {<stuff>}` in it.

A `prop` list is similar. After you do `\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_tmpa_prop { a = x, b = y, c = zzz }` the `prop` variable will be a macro with:

```latex
\s__prop
\__prop_pair:wn a\s__prop {x}
\__prop_pair:wn b\s__prop {y}
\__prop_pair:wn c\s__prop {zzz}
```

so an arbitrarily large `prop` list will have arbitrarily many `\__prop_pair:wn <name>\s__prop {<value>}` in it. the basic difference is that here you have to store not only a value, but also its name, so the overhead is a tad higher. While with the `seq` variable you had `<stuff>` plus three tokens (`\__seq_item:n`, `{`, and `}`), with a `prop` variable you have `<name>`, `<value>`, plus 4 more tokens (`\__prop_pair:wn`, `\s__prop`, `{`, and `}`).

Of course that once the contents of either start to grow, the overhead becomes insignificant, so the choice is up to the usage. If you want to store a sequence of things, then use a `seq` variable. If you want to store things and give a name to each use a `prop` list. Either will have a small memory overhead compared to their contents.

Now returning to your question, there is no imposed limit on the number of items a `seq` variable can contain because there is no imposed limit on the size of a `\def` in TeX. It can store arbitrarily large definitions as long as they fit in the imposed amount of memory available for TeX. Thus, the answer to your question will be similar to the answer of “how big a `\def` can TeX store in its memory?”.

---

If I simply load `expl3` in a plain TeX file, create an (initially) empty `seq` variable, and ask for the memory stats:

```latex
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_test_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tracingstats1
\bye
```

I get this (with pdfTeX in a TeXLive 2019):

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9137 strings out of 494647
 176410 string characters out of 6148463
 160755 words of memory out of 5000000
 10799 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 543492 words of font info for 60 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1416 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,0n,59p,187b,317s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

XeTeX will show basically the same info, perhaps with a slight difference on the numbers, because it's fairly similar to pdfTeX. LuaTeX, on the other hand, will show a slightly different summary:

```
Here is how much of LuaTeX's memory you used:
 8789 strings out of 496318
 100000,154059 words of node,token memory allocated
 244 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 rule, 1 glyph, 27 glue_spec nodes
   avail lists: 2:10,3:3,5:3,7:2
 10892 multiletter control sequences out of 65536+600000
 60 fonts using 6755909 bytes
 61i,0n,59p,271b,446s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,100000s
```

because LuaTeX has a rather different memory management than its predecessors (see section **3.4.1 Memory allocation** of the LuaTeX manual). However, the underlying information is fairly similar. The next paragraphs will be based on the output of pdfTeX, but the same principles apply to the other engines, changing the numbers a little bit. I'll also use a `seq` variable because it's easier to build up programatically than a `prop` variable, but the principles are all the same.

If I add an item to that `seq` I don't see any difference at all in the memory usage. In fact, if I add a bunch of items to that `seq` variable I don't see any difference up to a certain point. I think (not sure, though) that the memory stats showed by TeX are the maximum amount used during the run, but at some point it clears some memory and when I populate the `seq` it uses that memory which will not show in the stats.

However, once I pass that point anything that is added to the `seq` variable counts in the memory. This code barely passes that threshold:

```latex
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_test_seq
% \int_step_inline:nn {751} { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_test_seq { 0123456 } }% No difference
  \int_step_inline:nn {752} { \seq_put_right:Nn \l_test_seq { 0123456 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tracingstats1
\bye
```

the memory usage is the same except for the `words of memory`, which increased from `160755` to `160769`. The other memory types are left untouched by this operation. If I add another item to that variable (by changing the `752` to `753` the `words of memory` increase to `160789`. Add another one and it goes to `160809`, always in steps of `20`. Why `20` you ask? Each added item is `\__seq_item:n {0123456}`, which are exactly `10` tokens (`\__seq_item:n`, `{`, 7 characters, and `}`), so this tells us that each token in a definition counts as two `words of memory` (perhaps because TeX represents a token by its character and category codes, so 2 words per token; but I'm just guessing here, sorry). If you were to use a `prop` list you would have to take into account the length of the name of each item, plus the extra tokens showed in the beginning of this answer.

Now we're getting somewhere. If I take the total `words of memory` available, subtract the number used, and divide by `20` I get an estimate of the number of 7-token items that I can still add to the sequence above, which is about `241962`, which will take an awful lot of time to run :)

To reduce the time it takes to build that sequence you can enlarge each item. Here is a code that adds 997-token items to the `seq` variable, which added to the 3 tokens of the `seq` variable, grows the sequence in steps of `2000` words of memory:

```latex
\input expl3-generic.tex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_test_seq
\int_step_inline:nn {2426} % Add 1 to see TeX blow up :)
  {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_test_seq
      { % Indentation is important even here :)
        0123456   012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
        0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\tracingstats1
\bye
```

The code above brings the memory to `4999713 words of memory out of 5000000` (`99.994%` :).

---

#### Conclusion (?)

This all means that you can (roughly) store `2400` 1000-token items in a `seq` variable when you are using pdfTeX or XeTeX. If you consider all the stored tokens to be ASCII characters, each 1000-token item is 1 kB, then you have approximately **2.4 MB** of memory available for this `seq` variable (or any other 2.4 MB definition). Of course, the `seq` variable has an intrinsic memory footprint of 3 tokens, so the smaller the items stored, the less usable space you have.

If you are using LuaTeX, the memory usage will be roughly similar to the other engines. The test above with LuaTeX used `100000,5906145 words of node,token memory allocated` (that is, `100000 words of node and 5906145 words of token memory`, the latter is the one we're interested in), which is about 20% more than pdfTeX. However LuaTeX has dynamic memory allocation so, quoting the manual:

> ‘Out of main memory’ errors can still occur, but the limiting factor is now the amount of RAM in your system, not a predefined limit.

so yes, you can go pretty wild on the loop counter if you are using LuaTeX :)

For other engines the memory can be enlarged by changing the value of `main_memory` in `texmf.cnf` (default is `5000000` words, 2.5 MB).

However, should you reach this point in a document you are probably better off saving that to an external file. One situation where you can exceed the memory limit is with an environment that grabs its contents in a macro combined with an absurdly large content, like in “[TeX capacity exceeded when externalizing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/491072/134574)”. However even in such cases something can be changed to drastically reduce memory usage somehow.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the answer I was looking for, you have done the exercise with plain `TeX`, with `(Lua)TeX` will it be the same?....Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL The same memory usage, approximately. The same limit, no. The test above with LuaTeX used `100000,5906145 words of node,token memory allocated` (that is, `100000 words of node and 5906145 words of token memory`, the latter is the one we're interested in), which is about 20% more than pdfTeX. However LuaTeX has dynamic memory allocation (see section 3.4.1 (Memory allocation) of the manual) so “‘Out of main memory’ errors can still occur, but the limiting factor is now the amount of RAM in your system, not a predefined limit”. So yes, you can go pretty wild on the loop counter :)

Comment: This is more interesting, that is, the maximum capacity depends on whether I decide to use `(Xe|pdf|Lua)LaTeX` ... If you have some time, you could extend your answer ... Agradecido nuevamente

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL ¡Done! :)

Comment: Great level response, the code (ugly, messy and unpolished) that was presented above was the basis for a small package of the type `question/answer` in which I am working. With this answer I think I can expand my original idea a bit more (I doubt that I will use the memory limit with any of my files). In words of Gustavo Cerati .... "Gracias Totales"...

Comment: I could extend your answer and make the comparison between `l3seq` and `l3prop`?, I have updated the example code to make the comparisons (but I haven't modified the question). Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Done!

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation regarding `l3seq` and `l3prop` (for some reason I thought `l3prop` was more efficient). If you have some time left you can check a question in the `expl3` tag. Greetings

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I don't think their efficiency can be easily compared. One stores ordered items, the other named items. However both use loops to search for a specific item in the variable, the difference is that ones uses `\pdfstrcmp` and the other `\ifnum` to check for the item, so I'd say (without any evidence) that `seq` is more efficient, but probably by a minimum amount. It's really down to how you want organise the input. What question do you mean? This one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/496965/134574? I already saw it, but `\scantokens` is still a bit of a mistery to me...

Comment: Thank you @ Phelype, I think the answer to that question is no `:(` , I checked `l3tl.dtx` I realized that it plays with `\newlinechar` and `\endlinechar` and it won't work in my case. You can take a look at my other question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/497079/7832)