# How do you compact a code that expands \macro and store it in an expl3 sequence?

Tags: macros, expansion, expl3

I'm trying to rewrite some of the codes I have by following the correct `expl3` rules. With the following code I define the `scontents` environment that encapsulates the `filecontentsdefmacro` environment of the `filecontentsdef` package using `xparse/expl3`. Everything works OK, I get to record the content of `scontents` in a sequence and then I can access it, the theme is the way I get it. The original package has the `\filecontentsexec` macro to run the content recorded by the `filecontentsdefmacro` environment, but, I haven't been able to make this work for me and have had to copy almost directly the definition directly from the package and write it in terms of `expl3`. Like this:

```
% Expand \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl and pass to seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
      {
         \tex_newlinechar:D = 13
         \tex_everyeof:D = { \exp_not:N }
         \exp_not:N \scantokens \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } }
         \tex_newlinechar:D = 10 \scan_stop:
       }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      {
        \exp_not:N \_scontents_append_contents:nn 
          { 
            \exp_not:V \l_scontents_name_seq_tl 
          } 
          { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } 
      }
    \l_tmpb_tl % add to seq
  }
```

The problem is that I use (and abuse) the `:D` argument that as far as I've read, it shouldn't be occupied, my idea was to be able to use something shorter, similar to this:

```
% Expand \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl and pass to seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  {
    \_scontents_append_contents:nn { \l_scontents_name_seq_tl } 
      { 
        \filecontentsexec \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } }
      }
  }
```

This is the complete example file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef}[2019/04/20]
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl }

\keys_define:nn { scontents }
  {
    save-env  .tl_set:N   = \l_scontents_name_seq_tl,
    save-env  .initial:n  = contents,
    show-env  .bool_set:N = \l_scontents_show_env_tl,
    show-env  .initial:n  = false  
  }

% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/215571/7832
\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_append_contents:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      {
        \seq_new:c { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq }
      }
    \seq_gput_right:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#1_seq } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn #1 #2
  {
    \seq_item:cn { g_scontents_seq_name_#2_seq } { #1 }
  }

\ProvideExpandableDocumentCommand{\getstored}{ O{1} m }
  {
    \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

% Define environment ( wrap \filecontentsdefmacro ) 
% Adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/487746/7832
\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{ scontents }{}
  {
    \char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
    \scontents_start_environment:w
  }
  {
    \scontents_stop_environment:
    \scontents_atend_environment:
  }

% Delaying [key=val] for environment
\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_environment_keys:w [#1]
  {
    \keys_set:nn { scontents } { #1 }
  }

% Star environment
\group_begin:
\char_set_catcode_active:N \^^M
\cs_new_protected:Npn \scontents_start_environment:w #1 ^^M
  {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { \scontents_environment_keys:w #1 }
    \group_begin: % open a group for environment
    \use:c { filecontentsdefmacro } { \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } ^^M 
  }
\group_end:

% Stop environment
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_stop_environment:
  {
    \endfilecontentsdefmacro 
    \group_end:  % close a group for environment
  }

% Expand \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl and pass to seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
      {
         \tex_newlinechar:D = 13
         \tex_everyeof:D = { \exp_not:N }
         \exp_not:N \scantokens \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } }
         \tex_newlinechar:D = 10 \scan_stop:
       }
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpb_tl
      {
        \exp_not:N \_scontents_append_contents:nn 
          { 
            \exp_not:V \l_scontents_name_seq_tl 
          } 
          { \exp_not:V \l_tmpa_tl } 
      }
    \l_tmpb_tl % add to seq
  }

% Execution of the code after finishing the scontent environment 
\cs_new_protected:Nn \scontents_atend_environment:
  {
    \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
    \bool_if:NT \l_scontents_show_env_tl
      {
        \_scontents_getfrom_seq:nn { -1 }{ \l_scontents_name_seq_tl }
      }
    \cs_undefine:N \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % just for the example
\begin{document}
\section*{Test environment}
Test \verb+\begin{scontents}+ no \verb+[key=val]+\par

\begin{scontents}
Using \verb+scontents+ env no \verb+[key=val]+, save in 
\verb+contents+ with index 1. \footnote{AND footnotes !!}

\begin{verbatim}
      (A) verbatim environment
\end{verbatim}
\end{scontents}

Test \verb+\begin{scontents}[save-env=other]+\par

\begin{scontents}[save-env=other]
Using \verb+scontents+ env with \verb+[save-env=other]+, save in  
\verb+other+ with index 1.

\begin{verbatim*}
      (B) verbatim environment
\end{verbatim*}
\end{scontents}

\section*{Show stored contents}
\getstored[1]{other}
\getstored[1]{contents}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to write the code following the "rules" (and what I have learned in the forum), if something is badly written (related to `expansion` or `cs`), please correct me accordingly.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can't use `\filecontentsexec` the way you do. What you want is to pass the processed result of that macro to `\_scontents_append_contents:nn`. As `\filecontentsexec` is not fully expandable, this is not going to work. You should only use this macro in the normal execution mode, not as part of token list manipulations.

However, you can shorten your `\_scontents_macro_to_seq:` macro a bit, because the material inside `\l_tmpa_tl` of your first version is expandable. Using temporary variables is not necessary then, you can just pass the expanded result to `\_scontents_append_contents:nn` directly:

```
% Expand \l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl and pass to seq
\cs_gset_protected:Nn \_scontents_macro_to_seq:
  {
    \exp_args:NNx \_scontents_append_contents:nn \l_scontents_name_seq_tl 
      {
        \tex_newlinechar:D = 13
        \tex_everyeof:D = { \exp_not:N }
        \exp_not:N \scantokens \exp_after:wN { \tl_use:c { l_scontents_macro_tmp_tl } }
        \tex_newlinechar:D = 10 \scan_stop:
      }
  }
```

(If you are not familiar with the set of `\exp_args:` functions `\exp_args:NNx \A \B \C` is equivalent to `\A \B {<full expansion of \C>}`.)

Comment: Thank you very much, it is more less what I was looking for, consultation, is there any way to avoid using `:D` and `\scantokens`, that is to say, to place something more in the line of `expl3`?

Comment: What you could use is `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`. Looking at the code, this function seems to implement basically the same pattern as your `\scantokens` code. I'm not sure how well that would work in conjunction with `filecontentsdef`, though.

Comment: I think I once tried, but I never really understood how to use `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`, if you have some time, could you extend your answer using `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn`? If `expl3` has a function equal to `\scantokens` I think it would be correct to use it. Saludos

Comment: I've tried to reimplement that method using `\tl_set_rescan` but I couldn't make it work. Not sure if this function isn't supposed to work with verbatim commands or I'm just using it wrong. Also for multiline text all spaces seem to be stripped even at the beginning of lines.

Comment: Now that I remember, I made the attempt some time ago (and a poorly worded question that I then deleted). Apparently you can't set `\newlinechar` in the `{setup}` of `\tl_set_rescan` (I think).