# Why \tl_set_rescan fails without a leading space char?

Tags: expl3

This is the code, it compiles (please, don't ask me what it's for):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand\foo[1]{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_ebnf_tl { }
  \tl_set_rescan:Nno \l_ebnf_tl {}{#1}
  \l_ebnf_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\foo{ \textdollar}
\end{document}
```

However, if I modify the line with `textdollar` to this one (I just remove the leading space):

```
\foo{\textdollar}
```

It prints this:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\l_ebnf_tl ->\?
               -cmd \textdollar \?\textdollar
l.10 \foo{\textdollar}
```

What is this about and how to fix? I don't need this space character over there.

Comment: You are expanding the argument once.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm not an expert, but I see that people use `\tl_set_rescan` with two arguments: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/496965/how-do-use-setup-in-tl-set-rescannnn-to-replace-scantokens

Comment: What would be the reason for doing rescan on `\textdollar`?

Comment: sure but why are you using`o`? This expands `#1` once and break if `#1` starts with `\textdollar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expansion of `\textdollar` is (courtesy of `\tl_analysis_show:N`)

```
The token list \textdollar contains the tokens:
>  \?-cmd (control sequence=macro:#1#2->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \ETC.)
>  \textdollar (control sequence=macro:->\?-cmd \textdollar \?\textdollar )
>  \?\textdollar (control sequence=\long macro:->\UseTextSymbol {TS1}\te\ETC.).
```

The first control sequence cannot ordinarily be obtained, but it obviously can with `\csname ?-cmd\endcsname`. Also the third control sequence has been obtained with `\csname ?\string\textdollar\endcsname`.

You're applying `\tl_set_rescan:no {} {\textdollar}` and TeX duly expands once `\textdollar` before performing `\tl_set_rescan:nn` and you get

```
\tl_set_rescan:nn {} {\?-cmd \textdollar \?\textdollar}
```

But at this point, category codes are the standard ones, so the rescanning interprets the input as

```
\?•-•c•m•d• •\textdollar•\?•\textdollar
```

(where `•` is used to separate one token from another)

Now `\?` is usually undefined and you get the error.

If you add a space like in

```
\foo{ \textdollar}
```

the `o` specifier means that the *first* token in the argument is tried for expansion. It's not expandable, so nothing happens and the rescanning produces a space followed by `\textdollar`.

Comment: Long story short, replacing `\tl_set_rescan:Nno` with `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn` solved the problem